# Model Builder - Iterate user selected KML files as input - NOT a folder as input

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, iteration

[image]I am trying to create an iterative KML to layer geoprocessing model.

The goal: I want to prompt the user to select specific .kml files in a directory to process as well as prompt for the output folder. Pretty straight forward except...

The problem: The 'Iterate Files' iterator would seem to be the way to go BUT it requires a user to select a FOLDER and then it will process every file within the folder. Constantly updated .kml files are received on a regular basis and stored in the same folder...so, I do NOT want the user to have to select a Folder. I want to give the user the freedom to choose specific .kml files.

Below is a screen shot of the model for reference. The 'Iterate Files' iterator is great because it allows me to use the "Name" property as an inline variable for the resulting .gdb and Layer name.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Iterate MultiValue with a Multiple Value File as the input.[image] You can set a filter on the parameter to only allow kml and kmz files to be selected.[image]